# How can I get a SQL Server md5 hash to match a previous php md5 hash?

Tags: php, sql-server, hash, md5

I have a SQL Server 2014 table filled with MD5 hashses generated by php using the php `$hash = md5($password);` command. Now that we are moving to a tighter security model, I would like to be able to within a Stored Procedure take a password and match it to the previously stored md5 hash.

Problem comes when the md5 hash returned by SQL is different than the one returned by php.

When I use

```
SELECT username, 
    [password],  
    master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), [password])), 1, 0) AS Test, 
    HASHBYTES('MD5', [password]) AS MD5 
FROM myTable 
WHERE username=@username
```

I get:

```
Password = 28d744960521b00fd7c4a9e7e7d4d3a3, 
Test = 172b078903f8f16098fea3df31ee8989, and 
MD5 = 0x172B078903F8F16098FEA3DF31EE8989
```

The MD5 expression is normal tsql and the Test expression I got online, but as you can see, neither of their results equal what I originally stored from php's md5() expression.

Any idea why these are different, and better yet, is there a way I can format the tsql command to give me a match on the stored php md5 value?

Comment: you mean the value in column [password] in your table is already hashed ?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies! I was sending the value [password] to the sql hash sequence not the inputted variable @password! So I was receiving in Test and MD5 a hash of a hash, not the hash of the original password.

Interestingly enough, the fancy `master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), [password])), 1, 0)` is needed to remove the leading `0x` to get the right match.

Comment: This is the best solution online. I couldn't get the SQL Server md5 to match the PHP md5, except if I use this method. Thanks!