# MD5 Hashing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The SQL MD5 hashing function returns a different result to others e.g. passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator

First of all I pick a source string at random, which in this case is:

```
спасибо(:
```

Providing the Miracle salad MD5 generator with my source string returned the following result:

```
e1295bb206823340c694b795c17eb4c5
```

The query I used to generate an MD5 hash in SQL Server is as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('md5', 'спасибо(:'), 2)
```

...which returned the following result:

```
C4E6F99E8CD676020DC7D3E13612D51A
```

Please can someone help me figure out a) why are they different and b) an Sql query that will return the same result as passwordsgenerator.net?

Comment: https://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/

Comment: i think passwordgenerator.net is wrong. The text 'tést' has md5 'AB176F76FEC779A347D4096384EDB094', and in mssql it says '147ACB11180BB723C38841D4845E207D' . When trying to convert 'test', both give same result!

Comment: that web site is correct it give a correct result i try it many time.

Comment: ok, website seems to be OK.

Comment: The text 'test' has md5 '098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6', and in sql '098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6'.   the web site is correct.

Comment: When I run your `sql` code (without the unnecessary extra closing parenthesis) I get `6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A`, which is the same as the answer from @Luuk but different to your question.  I think you are doing something wrong that is not included in your question here.

Comment: @alex-sh passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator calculates `md5` sum using utf-8 encode string. How do you use this generator in your application?

Comment: i don't use it i just compare the result between the site and sql

Answer (score 2):

**Explanations**

One possible explanation is that this online tool calculates the `MD5` hash of an `UTF8` encoded string. I'm able to reproduce this behaviour with `PHP` and `T-SQL`.

Possible solutions are:

- convert your `UTF-8` text to `cyrillic` text in your application and after that use `HASHBYTES`
- encode your `cyrillic` text to `UTF-8` in the database using functions like [ToUTF](https://gist.github.com/sevaa/f084a0a5a994c3bc28e518d5c708d5f6). I use this function just for the test, but I suggest to make the conversion in your application.

**Test, using PHP and conversion from UTF8 to CP1251**

PHP:

```
<?php
$input = "спасибо(:";
$input = iconv("UTF8", "CP1251", $input);
echo md5($input);
?>
```

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @input varchar(32) = 'спасибо(:'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), HASHBYTES('md5', @input), 2)
```

Output:

```
C4E6F99E8CD676020DC7D3E13612D51A
```

**Test, using online generator and UDF**

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @input varchar(32) = 'спасибо(:'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('md5', dbo.ToUTF8(@input)), 2)
```

Output:

```
E1295BB206823340C694B795C17EB4C5
```

**Notes**

Default collation for test database is `Cyrillic_General_CS_AS`.

Comment: Please can you include the listing for your dbo.ToUTF8 function? I did a search and found some, but the output returned 6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins There is a link is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I still get 6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A. Can you double check?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins Because it's a cyrillic text, my test database collation is `Cyrillic_General_CS_AS`. With server default collation the output is `6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A`.

Comment: Phew, I eventually got there. `DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(MAX) = dbo.ToUTF8(N'спасибо(:');SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('md5', @input COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI), 2)` works. Thanks for your help, Zhorov.

Answer (score 1):

The output of this

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(64),HASHBYTES('md5','спасибо(:'),2), HASHBYTES('md5','спасибо(:')
```

is

```
6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A                                 0x6010E112D213366938E6C894F1BE9C2A
```

so the output of the function includes the '0x', see [How can I get a SQL Server md5 hash to match a previous php md5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906413/how-can-i-get-a-sql-server-md5-hash-to-match-a-previous-php-md5-hash)

Comment: the output with out 0x